# How to return actionResult enums value Razor page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

***my razor pages***
I'm trying to capture the value in dropdown with javascript

```
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ddlEnum").change(function() {
        var display = document.getElementById("ddlEnum");
         
    });
});

</script>
```

**I want to send the value on this side with the button.**
first, I return with foreach. I see the incoming enum values, but I can't select them.

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
{

    if (item.Priotrity == PriotrityEnums.Do)
    {


        <table class="table table-danger">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Task Adı</th>
                    <th>Task Önceliği</th>
                    <th>Task Durumu</th>
                    <th>Durum Opsiyonları</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>

                    <td>@item.Title</td>
                    <td>@EnumExtensions.GetDisplayName(PriotrityEnums.Do)</td>
                    @if (@item.Status == StatusEnums.Wait)
                    {
                        <td>@EnumExtensions.GetDisplayName(StatusEnums.Wait)</td>
                    }
                    else if (@item.Status == StatusEnums.Continuing)
                    {
                        <td>@EnumExtensions.GetDisplayName(StatusEnums.Continuing)</td>
                    }
                    else if (@item.Status == StatusEnums.Completed)
                    {
                        <td>@EnumExtensions.GetDisplayName(StatusEnums.Completed)</td>
                    }
               <td style="width:180px">
                    <form  method="post" asp-action="ChangeStatus">

              
                   <select id="ddlEnum" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<StatusEnums>()">       </select>
              
              
                    <input type="submit"  value="Kaydet"  >
                    
                      </form>
                       </td>
                
         


                 
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
```

Here I need to meet the incoming value.
It captures the value as a javascripty object, but when I send it on the IActionResult side, it returns 0.
Controller:

```
public IActionResult ChangeStatus(int enumValue)
{
    //if (enumValue.Equals StatusEnums.Completed)
    //{


    //}

    return View();
```

Answer (score 0):

When passing the selected value, it is necessary to add the `name` attribute to ensure that it is consistent with the name of the parameter received by the controller.

Below is my test code, it works fine.

Cshtml:

```
<form  method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ChangeStatus">
    <select id="ddlEnum" name="enumValue" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<StatusEnums>()"></select>   
    <input type="submit"  value="Kaydet" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult ChangeStatus(int enumValue)
{
    return View();
}
```

Test Result:

[image]